# Make an async API request blocking with Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

As the title implies, I'm currently working with an API that has an async callback method. I'd like to be able to WAIT for the result before proceeding with the rest of the code (making an existing async call somewhat synchronous, if that makes sense). Is this possible with coroutines? This is what my code looks like right now, but the request is still called multiple times (I'm new to coroutines).

```
class TokenAuthenticator @Inject constructor(val prefs: AppPrefs) : Authenticator {
    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        if (response.code() == ApiErrorCode.UNAUTHORIZED) {
            Timber.w("Unauthorized. Refreshing token...")

            val token: String? = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main) { refreshToken() }

            token?.let {
                return response
                        .request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
                        .build()
            }
        }

        when (response.code()) {
            ApiErrorCode.UNAUTHORIZED -> Timber.w("Tried to refresh token. Failed?")
            else -> Timber.d("NOT refreshing token, response code was: ${response.code()}")
        }

        return response.request()
    }

    private suspend fun refreshToken() = suspendCoroutine<String?> {
        SomeApi.getValidAccessToken(object : TokenCallback {
            override fun onSuccess(accessToken: String?) {
                Timber.d("Token successfully retrieved. Storing to prefs...")
                prefs.userAuthToken = accessToken
                it.resume(accessToken)
            }

            override fun onError(errorData: Any?) {
                Timber.e("Error retrieving token")
                it.resume(null)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put all of your sequence in a `launch` coroutine, and then you call `await()` on the result of your `async` call, you can achieve what you're describing. But in that case, you might as well use `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` to simplify it. `async` is meant for parallel decomposition.`withContext` is a more straight-forward way to do sequential tasks in the background and finishing them before continuting.

Comment: `runBlocking` should never be used anywhere but directly in `main()` or in a unit test. I would say your `authenticate` function should be marked `suspend` so you can simply call `refreshToken()` without wrapping it in another coroutine.

Comment: `but the request is still called multiple times` I don't understand what you mean here. Your code looks like it should achieve your goal, which is turning async API usage into sync. You don't have to specify `Dispatchers.Main`, BTW. You can safely use just `runBlocking { ... }`

Comment: Just a note, you could have achieved the same with just a `CompletableFuture`, no coroutines involved.